# Iterating through dask array chunks

Tags: python, arrays, dask, chunks

I am trying to manually iterate through the chunks of a dask array, one by one, and apply my computation.  I understand that a benefit of dask is that it can to do the iteration for me, but my computation is failing (for reasons that I don't think are related to dask) and I want to iterate through manually for the purpose of debugging. How would I do that?

I am imagining something like:

```py
import dask.array as da
data = da.random.randint(0, 30, size=(1_000, 100, 100), chunks=(-1, 10, 10))

for chunk in data.iterchunks():
    # chunk would contain some information about which chunk I have access to, 
    # and I could somehow get the data contained in that chunk
    chunk_data = get_chunk(chunk)
    my_function(chunk_data)
```

Where the `chunk` that I get back has some information about which chunk I am in, and there would also be get the data for that chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the data within each chunk using the [`arr.blocks`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.Array.blocks.html#dask-array-array-blocks) property. The BlockView object has an array-like interface, but accessing an element in the BlockView array returns the selected chunk(s) in the original array:

```py
In [11]: data
Out[11]: dask.array<randint, shape=(1000, 100, 100), dtype=int64, chunksize=(1000, 10, 10), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>

In [12]: data.blocks
Out[12]: <dask.array.core.BlockView at 0x1730b2da0>

In [13]: data.blocks.shape
Out[13]: (1, 10, 10)

In [14]: data.blocks[0, 0, 0]
Out[14]: dask.array<blocks, shape=(1000, 10, 10), dtype=int64, chunksize=(1000, 10, 10), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>

In [15]: data.blocks[0, 0, 0].compute()
Out[15]:
array([[[14,  5, 24, ..., 25, 20,  6],
        [17, 12,  2, ..., 27, 13, 18],
        [13, 25,  2, ...,  7,  5, 22],
        ...,
        [12, 22, 26, ..., 15,  4, 11],
        [ 0, 26, 28, ..., 22, 14,  4],
        [ 9, 21, 14, ..., 15, 18, 21]],

       ...,

       [[ 3,  2, 20, ..., 27,  0, 12],
        [21, 17,  7, ..., 23,  3, 23],
        [24, 13,  0, ..., 26,  1,  0],
        ...,
        [ 5, 25,  6, ..., 22,  6, 16],
        [16, 25, 21, ..., 22, 14, 15],
        [ 8, 20, 17, ..., 29, 13,  1]]])
```

So in your case, you could loop through all blocks with the following:

```py
In [34]: for inds in itertools.product(*map(range, data.blocks.shape)):
    ...:     chunk = data.blocks[inds]
    ...:     my_function(chunk)
```

This will be slow, but it does I think what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data.chunks` instead of `data.iterchunks()`.

Comment: That gives me the size of the chunks (here `(1000,)
(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)`) but not the actual data values. Do you know how I would convert from the chunk sizes to actual blocks of data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`da.map_blocks`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.array.map_blocks.html) and avoid the `for`-loop:

```py
import dask.array as da
data = da.random.randint(0, 30, size=(1_000, 100, 100), chunks=(-1, 10, 10))
mapped_data = da.map_blocks(my_function, data)
# This is equivalent
mapped_data = data.map_blocks(my_function)
```